# During a lightening storm is it significantly more dangerous to be in a body of water than on land?

Tags: electricity

Most people think that if you're in a body of water and lightening strikes the water anywhere near you, you instantly die.  Is this true?  (I'm almost certain it is not true.)

So in general, I'm in a swimming pool the size of a football field, either swimming on the surface, swimming under the water, or standing shoulder deep.  My friend is standing in the middle of a grassy football field and a lightening storm passes over both of us.  Am I in significantly more danger than my friend?  Why / how so?

Comment: https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/4282/is-it-necessary-to-leave-a-pool-during-a-thunderstorm and https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/92571/would-beetees-electrocution-plan-work-and-kill-the-tributes-in-the-lake

Comment: That other question is phrased as "is this movie realistic".  And I doubt the answer is correct.  I'd like to get another answer here.